# what is the use of sessionId in Dialogflow Nodejs API

Tags: node.js, session, dialogflow-es

Just wanted to get the details on session Id value in Dialogflow NodeJS API.

```
const sessionId = 'temp-session';
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
```

We get the project id from the Dialogflow console, but if I am passing session id as temp-session- Date.now(), it is not behaving as expected. If I am passing only temp-session, it is working fine.

Do we need to maintain the same value for the same client? Any documentation for this?
Any pattern or name policy for session id or we can give any length data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `session-id` is to maintain context and flow of the conversation. **If the session-id is same, DialogFlow will treat it as the part of same conversation.**

So you should put same session-id for same client for that particular session only. i.e if same user is coming next day then session-id should be different than previous day, because obviously it is a different conversation.

Also, if you are putting `temp-session` as session-id for all the clients then DialogFlow will think all the requests are coming from same clients and part of same conversation.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: 0

How to bind different session in different user, and same user is use same session id. thank you very much.